# BigQuery: How to simplify this SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This might not be limited to BigQuery but SQL in general.

I have this SQL and want to exclude when the 1st field ("code") is NULL.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'#\d+') code, COUNT(1)
FROM mydataset.mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

This is what I ended up found working:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'#\d+') code, COUNT(1)
FROM mydataset.mytable
WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'#\d+') is not NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'#\d+') code, COUNT(1)
FROM mydataset.mytable
WHERE code is not NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

I can go with what I found working but am wondering if there is more elegant way of doing the same. I guess I can add another outer SELECT but that's not what I want.

Comment: What does your data look like?  If you need to check whether a regex match happened in the `WHERE` clause, then you really have no choice except to call `REGEXP_EXTRACT` again.  As you mentioned, you could subquery and then check the `code` alias, but that means subquerying.

Comment: "data" field in the table is a free text and it can contain # to indicate the beginning of a certain code followed by numeric sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(data, r'#\d+') code, COUNT(1)
FROM mydataset.mytable
GROUP BY 1
HAVING code IS NOT NULL
```